# BitConverter С# в FreePascal/Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, pascal, freepascal, bytearray

Так выполняется перевод байт в целочисленный тип:

```
byte[] array_of_bytes = new byte[];
Int16 integer_value = BitConverter.ToInt16(array_of_bytes, 0);
```

- Int16 - С#
- Smallint - Pascal

Вопрос: как выполнить такое же преобразование два байта в массие в целочисленное значение?

Comment: Ссылочный тип (с домиком). http://tipidannih.narod.ru/ssilochnij.htm

Comment: По-моему так `p :^smallint; p=@array_of_bytes[0];  array_of_integers  = p^;` как избавится от p - обьявить ссылочный тип.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно оперировать ссылочными типами.
   http://tipidannih.narod.ru/ssilochnij.htm

Можно так, используя ссылочные типы

```
 type PSmallint = ^Smallint; // обьявляем ссылочный тип
 var array_of_bytes : ^byte;
     array_of_integers : Smallint; // Аналог Int16 


 Begin
   array_of_bytes =   GetMem(10 ); // указать ваш размер, или как-то получить.
   array_of_integers  =  PSmallint (@array_of_bytes[0])^; // Берём адрес, кастим к ссылочному типу, и домиком берём данные по адресу как int 16-битный
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        int[] intArray = new int[byteArray.Length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i += 4)
          {
            intArray[i / 4] = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, i);
          }
        return intArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  PSmallint = ^Smallint; // в новых версиях Delphi такой тип уже объявлен

var
  BytesArray: array of byte;
  SmallIntValue: Smallint;

begin
  SmallIntValue := PSmallint(@BytesArray[0])^;
end;
```

Было бы неплохо, для начала, как минимум задать размер массиву байт `Setlength(BytesArray, 2)`, иначе будет ошибка доступа.

Comment: Кстати, в случае динамического массива (array of byte или tbytes) можно написать просто: `SmallIntValue := PSmallint(BytesArray)^;`.

Comment: @Alekcvp, согласен, но если мы будем брать адрес нулевого элемента, то это в любом случае сработает, и нам не нужно будет помнить/разбираться какой же у нас массив используется. А оптимизатор компилятора все равно сгенерирует такой же код, как и на запись из вашего комментария.